# Significance of the Mmmm Bacon Hat and Dec 30?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

I just earned the Mmmm Bacon hat.  Will someone please explain the significance of bacon and December 30?

Comment: [You can find a complete list here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288803/a-list-of-what-each-of-the-winter-bash-2016-hats-are-named-after)

Comment: Pigs are sentient beings who feel all sorts of emotions and have a subjective experience of reality which has its own intrinsic value, much as yours does. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awNjy7OMG8I&list=PLarrSuuxY8ls4D5alab8qFWPrqkhvsZrl&index=30

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a reference to the [Bacon Day](https://www.daysoftheyear.com/days/bacon-day/).

Comment: LMAO -- everything IS better with bacon...

Comment: @Jesuisme tell that to Morrissey

Comment: [Even Morrissey can't live without bacon](http://eveningharold.com/2014/12/02/morrissey-admits-he-likes-bacon/), @dez.

Comment: @CodyGray some bacons are tastier than others

Comment: Then there is the ultimate bacon perversion: "Turkey Bacon".

Comment: _Lots of places choose different times to "celebrate" a Bacon Day_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/International_Bacon_Day